Is this question closeworthy?
I understand that this question(Can human based products be used successfully in making foodstuffs without any resulting products being flops or outing them as human based?) is gross, but is it really closeable?
It has 4 votes, and idk if it will get a 5th or not. 2 said it is opinion based. No, it is not. The chemistry of cooking is not fully opinion based. If you put pineapple in Jello it will not set nor will beans properly soften with salt added to uncooked dried bean, even if some folks like the resulting product. 1 vote said storybased, but this question is generic and can fit in many worlds. And 1 said it is gross, which while true, is not a valid VTC reason.
Is my question in the clear?

I didn't vote... but had I seen it in time I would have
The context of this question is tame. We've hosted a lot worse. We've even been chastised for it. So that's not the problem. But there are problems.

Can human based products be used successfully in making foodstuffs without any resulting products being flops or outing them as human based?


Can human based products be used successfully in making foodstuffs? Despite the trivial answer of obviously yes, this is a vague question. The world eats plants! But not the poisonous plants. The world eats meat! In fact it eats pretty much every portion of an animal's body... but not the waste products. In fact, humans eat just about everything. We even eat dirt. So obviously, yes, but that underscores the problem with this aspect of the question: it's too broad. Whole cookbooks have been written (and written and written) and you gave us nothing specific at all about it. So, VTC:Not About Worldbuilding as Described in the Help Center for violating the Book Rule.

without any resulting products being flops? Any? Any? You mean none? This is entirely subjective and story-based. I can't even imagine eating blood pudding, but whole societies adore it. I'm a fan of borscht but can't stand gazpacho. The better part of nine billion people on this Earth and I'd bet a tall milkshake that you can't find any two people who exactly agree in what they do or do not like to eat. So: "flop" is subjective and requires definition (VTC:Needs More Details) but it's also contextually relevant as it only has meaning in the context of your story (is it a flop because a critic said so? Because it financially failed? Because no one eats it? Because it doesn't appear in the popular cookbooks?), so VTC:Too Story-Based.

or outing them as human based? And before we can even talk about this one we're VTC:Needs More Focused because you're allowed only a single problem to solve. We express that idea as one-and-only-one-question. We're sometimes lenient when parts A and B separated by a conjunction are similar enough to be treated as a single problem and the OP was just rambling a bit... but in this case the two issues are entirely separate, so you have two questions when you're only allowed one.

But to continue... do you mean, "without anyone but the cannibals knowing that one or more of the ingredients came from a human being?" If so, VTC:Needs More Details because that's impossible to answer without knowing the technology level of the civilization and VTC:Too Story-Based because the resources of a small village are considerably different to those of a massive metropolis and all of that is irrelevant if you have one UFO conspiracy theorist health food nut in your story that reveals the horrific truth! The simple reality with both #3 and #2 is that they fall into the they will if you write your story that way and won't if you write your story that way category. There's no actual worldbuilding problem being solved, there's at best a vague request to help with writer's block or in some way trying to absolve oneself of responsibility for taking the proverbial path less traveled.


One last thing
You've been asked many times over the years to use the Sandbox for Proposed Questions. You've asked three questions on Meta and all three were questions asking why your question had been closed. Normally I'd applaud that initiative! But you've steadfastly refused to use the Sandbox. So this has officially become tedious.
You are...

Expected to adhere to the rules of Stack Exchange as found in the Help Center, the Tour, and the Close Reasons.

Expected to adhere to the policies of Worldbuilding.SE as found in the Help Center and here in Meta.

Expected to understand that popularity is not a justification for disobedience.

Expected to stop trying to convince people that the rules shouldn't apply to you.

Expected to use the Sandbox.


I do not believe for one moment that any of your questions were closed without some explanation of what you'd done wrong. Coming to Meta for the third time asking either for an explanation for the closure or a request to reopen because you disagree with the closure suggests you're ignoring the information you're receiving. I'm thinking if you're not willing to use the Sandbox and continue to abuse Meta because you don't like your badly written questions being closed that we should consider inviting the Moderators to suspend your WB.SE account for a while to help you remember that you have an obligation when using somebody else's website.
And that would be a real shame because your creativity is obviously amazing.
You just need to learn to use this tool on the owner's terms and not your own.

Ok, I will try to ask better questions. I look back at a good bit of my questions and agree they could be better and belong on Reddit (I am banned, lol!!!). One thing I should mention is the 1st post was justified as I gave enough details to answer it, but still  it got closed anyway for not enough details. Eventually got it reopened.

@ConanHighwoods I'm glad to hear you want to do better. Please start with the Sandbox and let me point out that whether or not you think there are enough details (or that the question is good enough) is irrelevant. Enough people disagreed to get the question closed. Please get into the habit of addressing their concerns rather than complaining they shouldn't be concerns. Thanks.

@ConanHighwoods -- Welcome to the club! Reddit sucks.

First and foremost I must concur that grossness is not any grounds for closing questions, I cut my teeth here on questions about bone powder and the blood pools from a rain of men and there have been many others.
Pretty sure my vote was the story-based one, I'm a writer so I think about story, often more than OPs might like me to. My rationale for that vote in particular is this; the author of any piece involving such an undertaking has too many legitimate options for using story elements to justify any outcome they want. You want the cult to succeed then negligence, corruption, spin doctors, and the removal of people who's honest epitaph would read "was inconvenient to someone with power" are all your friends. You want it to fail then there are story options around inspections, espionage, and just cult member characters running their mouth to the wrong person. Any combination of those elements is believable and because the end result of many of the options, and especially because you're, in part, asking about public reactions, is totally unpredictable (in the mathematical sense of predictability), the proper answer(s) to your query are all dependent on the story you want to tell.
I suspect, but don't know, they aren't my votes, that the "opinion-based" votes aren't so much concerned with the food production aspect but rather about the product(s) market success or failure being primarily a matter of opinion about the body public.

There is an expectation of keeping content on this site rated PG-13. https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7973/we-cannot-host-gruesome-depictions-of-violence-the-torture-tag-has-it-and-nee

@sphennings Huh I'd missed that, live and learn, few recent questions maybe need to be pointed at that one too. Yet a question can present a situation that is totally revolting without being particularly gruesome in nature. I can also think of a few questions that don't look too bad on the surface that led to some extremely gruesome places in the process of the research that went into the answers.

This is not necessarily above that.@sphennings

You do bring up a valid point about what the opinion based voters might have been thinking, but the truth is, in the 21st century world this would not even come close to beating out the worst product flop in history. This would make New Coke look like the greatest thing since sliced bread! The only viable answer for a real world setting is that  anyone involved in this product line would instantly catch the interest of law enforcement.

@elemtilas Depending where they were based and how much they had paid the "right people" the law may be no issue at all, not to the individual people at least.

Nah. I don't think that would fly. There is literally nowhere in the US or the West in general where you could pay enough bribes to put peoplemeat on the market. That just doesn't make sense!

@elemtilas There are plenty of place that supply food to those markets that aren't in those areas and are in places where a little hush money goes a long way, I've seen a few documentary films in the last year about just how little real food is sometimes in what we put in our mouth.

Yes. And No.

Introduction.  I'm not part of the close vote, but I might hop on that band waggon. Obviously, I've read your original query, and asked you for some clarifications. I read your query here in Meta and the associated answers and comments.

I don't find the question particularly gross the way you asked it. As I said in comments, you didn't violate site ratings or anything like that. I concur that a question being gross in and of itself is not a valid VTC. Otherwise, we'd likely have to close 300+ questions that mention cannibalism! There are lines that we don't cross, but you didn't go anywhere close to one of those places!

Assessment. My assessment of your question is: you asked a reasonable worldbuilding question; you gave us sufficient background so we could formulate a response; you gave us certain constraints that would help us give a definitive yes or no and the reasons why.

BUT. You left in the one constraint that actually makes your query truly unanswerable. Or rather, the constraint would allow me to both give you a definitive YES, along with reasons why, and also a definitive NO, along with reasons why.

Basically, you're asking two questions here: 1. can this thing happen in our world, and 2. can this thing happen in a different world. The one truly inviolable rule of the Stack Exchange site is that you only get to ask one question at a time. For us in WB.SE, this means that if you're working on a fictionalised real world setting, you could ask question 1; or if you're working on a scifi setting in a similar but different world, you could ask question 2.

Possible Solution.  This may seem like I'm picking at nits, but technically speaking, yes your question, as it stands, is closeworthy. So, I would give you a day to choose which of those options you're going for. If it's the real world, then give us the relevant worldbuilding context (e.g., is this some cult, or a mad scientist kind of thing?). If this is an alternate world, please tell us how the relevant religious, cultural, historical, social aspects differ from what's happening on Earth.

If I VTC, it would be for this reason: Needs more focus
This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.

For awareness, here is where you ask two completely separate questions:


This is obviously 1 question, unless you count flop and exposed for using human flesh as 2. This also takes place in a Earthlike setting at the most different, so yeah...I think your question definition is confused.

@ConanHighwoods --- No, you've got two questions. One asks can this happen in our world and the other question is can this happen in a similar world. This is very important to understand: SE only allows us to ask one focused question at a time. You can ask both questions! You just have to separate them into different questions.

@ConanHighwoods, you keep answering to whoever explains the issues with your questions stating that the question doesn't ask that. People answer to what they understand, not to what you think you have said. When over multiple questions they explain you the issue and apparently they never understand the question, the least you can do is listen and try to improve, rather than insisting that the question doesn't say that.

I added that so others know what setting it is, it is an edit. I just said similar because idk if it will be Earth exactly, but even if it is not, the answers will be close enough for either option, I can edit a / inbetween the 2 if it helps.@elemtilas

Just added my edits. @elemtilas

Do you, as a mod, feel this should have been closed? Please respond. @L.Dutch

The reopen was a fail, we need just 2 more votes. @elemtilas

@ConanHighwoods, yes. And by the way, considering that I, like most of other users here, have also something called a job and a real life which allow me to spend some of my free and unpaid time here, I would appreciate a less petulant and entitled tone in your requests. The whole world doesn't revolve around your questions.

Look, I will admit that I ask questions that are not very good. That being said, if I am being honest, certain users here(you included), are a bit...passive-aggressive. I understand 'bad' questions are annoying, but still. Like Dutch, I have picked up a vibe of you not wanting to interact with me for a while now. I have never been rude to you or others here. And my requests were not childish or entitled. It speaks when a group closes your decent/good very first question. Well hopefully we can have less toxic discourse soon. I kindly ask you to respond to this reply before deleting it. @L.Dutch

@ConanHighwoods You don't get to dictate how other people interpret your behavior. Based on the comments you have received it is clear that people  found your behavior to be rude and inappropriate. Telling us that you haven't been rude isn't going to change anything. Show us through your actions that you are trying to act in a less entitled manner.

"You don't get to dictate how other people interpret your behavior" Goes both ways. It is clear I found certain members here rude, and your reply will not negate this view. I am not saying I am innocent either though, I have been a bit blunt in comments. That being said, I have had folks here nitpick, call my questions trash, shootdown anything that breaks certain natural laws, close questions for totally wrong reasons, and users deleting my comments with context but leaving theirs that makes me look bad. Welp, for any of my genuine rudeness I put out unknowingly, I am sorry. @sphennings

@ConanHighwoods. So here's thing about how this would pan out in the real world. All the major religions and cultures and legal systems of Earth absolutely forbid cannibalism.  Just go with the US. Christianity strongly upholds the dignity of the human person. This is enshrined in our culture and laws. We don't eat people. Muslims don't eat people. Hindus don't eat people. Ethical Atheists don't eat people. Nones don't eat people. It's immoral. It's unethical. It's illegal. There is NO WAY you could ever get a humanburger to market without an outcry from the public, without being (cont)

(cont) excoriated on social media, without the FDA shutting your organisation down and without multiple law enforcement agencies bringing people in for serious questioning. So much for question 1! Now, on another similar world, you, the worldbuilder, could posit a universe that God did not create, that has no religions like Christianity and has no concepts sophont dignity. Cultures there might find no issue with cannibalism. It might even be a glorious thing to do! A restaurant like "Pop's Burgers" might have an entirely new meaning! In this kind of world, where the rules (cont)

(cont) are completely different, there wouldn't be the moral, ethical and legal issues surrounding what you're trying to do. This would be question 2! I hope you can appreciate the difference. It concerns me that I actually had to spell this out, but this is where we're going when we talk about the SE format only allowing one question at a time! This is what I wanted you to distinguish in your edit.
